# get custom configuration into email template (Magento)

Tags: php, email, magento

hyee . im not so good in explanation, but i'll try.
how to get data from configuration in magento to email template. example, i'll already add new field on store information which is on:

Configuration > General > Store Information

field that i add is gst no which is the code as below.

system.xml

```
<fields>
                    <gst_no>
                        <label>GST No</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>31</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                    </gst_no>
</fields>
```

and it function as expected. now how do i call this value on email template. example like

```
{{var store_email}}
```

on the other words, data is work as variable. 
or if there is a way to set GST field as global variable like email, contact phone and etc. I already try `{{config path="general/store_information/gst_no"}}` but is not work.On php level it would be work like this`Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/gst_no');`

thanks in advance :)

Comment: how ? sorry for my bad explanation . what i meant to ask is, call custom data from configuration to email .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to the right way.

Add **{{config path="general/store_information/gst_no"}}** in you email template.

Now Login to admin panel and navigate to System->Permissions->Variables

Click on Add new variable and fill the text box with **general/store_information/gst_no**. Set **Is Allowed** to *yes*

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thanks makwana, its work. hahha :)
i would like to ask a little bit. 
in this case, we need to create add permission right ? how to set general/store_information/gst_no to gst_no only. what i meant is like call the global variable like **{{var store_email}}**. **{{config path="general/store_information/gst_no"}}** to **{{var store_gst_no}}**